# MySql prepared update query fails

Tags: php, mysql

These are my codes:

```
$stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET u_lpwd = ? WHERE u_id=? LIMIT 1");
$stmt1->bind_param("si", $pwd, $uid);
$stmt1->execute();
if ($stmt1->affected_rows > 0){
    echo 'password has been updated successfully.';
} else {
    echo 'password update failed.';
}
```

Looks like the query is getting executed, but record is not being updated. Here is the report in SQLYog:

```
1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings

Query: UPDATE users SET u_lpwd = 'nAJR9d4iVeOTS6D3JiPRVSMXgBRGqTKNo' WHERE u_id= 15 LIMIT 1

0 row(s) affected

Execution Time : 0.153 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.153 sec
```

Comment: Stupid question: Did you commit your transaction after performing the update?

Comment: Check with a SELECT to see if the value was set. If you try to set a value with the same value, mysql will return 0 rows affected.

Comment: I was trying to update with the same value, hence it failed. Thanks GUDO for the tip.

Comment: try your query directly in mysql data base is it working? or it may be the u_lpwd having already value='nAJR9d4iVeOTS6D3JiPRVSMXgBRGqTKNo'   that may be a reson it gives 0 row affected because of no change in the value.

Comment: "UPDATE users SET u_lpwd = 'nAJR9d4iVeOTS6D3JiPRVSMXgBRGqTKNo' WHERE u_id= 15  AND  u_lpwd<>'nAJR9d4iVeOTS6D3JiPRVSMXgBRGqTKNo' LIMIT 1"      hope this will helps you.

Comment: @RNmalek did you read the OP's comment at all? He was updating with same value, hence nothing happened..

Answer (score 0):

May is the white-space the problem

```
u_id= 15
```

It seems that there is no Entiry in Database